# XmlNode.AppendChild fails

Tags: c#, xml, system.xml

I am creating XML with C#. I want to append `item` to `content`. I create an XmlNode with `CreateItem`, but I can't seem to append it to the `contentElement`.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode contentElement = doc.CreateElement("content");
doc.AppendChild(contentElement);
contentElement.AppendChild(CreateItem);

public XmlNode CreateItem(XmlDocument doc, string hint, string type, string title, string value) {
    XmlNode item = doc.CreateElement("item");

    XmlAttribute Hint = doc.CreateAttribute("Hint");
    Hint.Value = hint;
    XmlAttribute Type = doc.CreateAttribute("Type");
    Type.Value = type;

    item.Attributes.Append(Hint);
    item.Attributes.Append(Type);

    XmlNode tit = doc.CreateElement("Title");
    tit.InnerText = title;

    item.AppendChild(tit);

    XmlNode val = doc.CreateElement("Value");
    val.InnerText = value;

    item.AppendChild(val);

    return item;
}
```

Comment: What is `CreteItem`, and where is it defined?

Comment: public xmlNode, line 5

Comment: Out of interest, is there any reason you can't use LINQ to XML? It's generally a *much* nicer API for this...

Comment: And it would really help if you'd show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - just a small console app, appropriately formatted etc.

Comment: thanks, but do you know how invoke it with the arguments it needs? i just know how to append a single child with no arguments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call the `CreateItem` method, so it did not actually create an `<item>`, so there was nothing to append.

How about:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    var content = doc.CreateElement("content");
    doc.AppendChild(content);
    var item = CreateItem(doc, "the hint", "the type", "the title", "the value");
    content.AppendChild(item);
}

public static XmlElement CreateItem(XmlDocument doc, string hint, string type, string title, string value)
{
    var item = doc.CreateElement("item");
    item.SetAttribute("Hint", hint);
    item.SetAttribute("Type", type);
    AppendTextElement(item, "Title", title);
    AppendTextElement(item, "Value", value);
    return item;
}

public static XmlElement AppendTextElement(XmlElement parent, string name, string value)
{
    var elem = parent.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(name);
    parent.AppendChild(elem);
    elem.InnerText = value;
    return elem;
}
```

Note the `var` keyword. See Type Inference, a.k.a ["Implicitly Typed Local Variables"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).